# Disable the X button on a message box

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a VBScript program, and I don't know how to disable the X button on a message box. Can you please help me?

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?516092-RESOLVED-Disable-MsgBox-Close

Comment: @NickODell That's a VB6 answer.

Comment: A more important question is why you would want to do that. I think what you're asking is actually impossible. This forum posting http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Disable-the-39X39-button-on-MsgBox-m74120.aspx examines some possible work-arounds like making an .HTA just to act as your msgbox.

Comment: What if I'm wrapping it to exe via iexpress.exe? Even other vbs to exe can't do that (probable exception is ExeScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Daniel Cook said, you could make an HTA as your message box. (Even though I haven't been using HTA for a while).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You basically can't. However...

If you use the VbOkOnly option or Popup function in place of MsgBox, when the user clicks on X this should be interpreted as clicking OK. The execution of the script will be continued.

[Click here for more info..](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Disable-the-39X39-button-on-MsgBox-m74120.aspx)

Comment: @Praveen Please do not use code highlighting for random code-related words; use them only for actual code snippets, please

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is that a consensus? I see code inline highlighting used like that (for keywords, variable names) all the time, and also have been using it myself for ages! Maybe you could point me to some meta discussion about it? Thanks.

Comment: @bfavaretto Not easy finding these! Here go a couple: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164309/152134) [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155904/152134)

Comment: @Andrew It's more controversial than I thought. I certainly agree it shouldn't come to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back), but I wouldn't be so strict. In this answer, I would be fine with editing out the highlighting just on `X` and `OK`. Nevertheless, you have my vote! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto My biggest thing, personally, is people who clog the edit queue with edits that are nothing but 'highlighting' words like that. Though Praveen did also change the bare link into a "click here for more info" (I'm not a fan of those, either... but that's another story!)